# private scope and inheritance in java

Tags: java

Consider this simple java code :

```
class A {
    private int a = 10;

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + "    " + a);

    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public void p1() {
        print();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.p1();
    }
}
```

If you will run the code , the value that gets printed is B 10 .
My question is if "a" is not inherited when we use "private" modifier but the method is , then there is method print() in class B now but  "a" is not part of the class since it is private, so how is it that the compiler doesn't throw error when we try to access it by saying scope of "a " is private ?

Comment: Yes this question is obvious (which is a subjective term) but it is well written and backed up by an easy to follow example. I don't therefore understand the downvote.

Comment: The `.` operator travels up the class-hierarchy until it finds a definition for the method. `print()` is not copied into `B`.

Comment: @Bathsheba - I tried 3 times to parse that 4 line sentence ... and failed.  You must be using some other definition of "well written" that I'm not aware of :-)

Comment: Surely this **must** be a duplicate, though. My list of [java] duplicates isn't as extensive as my list of [javascript] duplicates...

Comment: There most likely is a conceptual duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JLS ([8.3. Field Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)) states this:

> A class inherits from its direct superclass and direct superinterfaces all the non-private fields of the superclass and superinterfaces that are both accessible to code in the class and not hidden by a declaration in the class.
>
> A private field of a superclass might be accessible to a subclass - for example, if both classes are members of the same class. **Nevertheless, a private field is never inherited by a subclass.**

But, what does "inherit" actually mean?

What it actually means is that the name of the (inherited) method or field is present in the namespace of the subclass.  A `private` method is not present.  It cannot be named in the namespace of the subclass.

On the other hand, the private field of a superclass must be present in an instance of the subclass.  If it wasn't present, then methods declared in the superclass that use the private field *could not function*.

But then we have the bit about nested classes; e.g.

```
public class Outer {
    class A {
       private int a;
       ...
    }
    class B extends A {
        private int b1 = a;  // Compilation error
        // field 'a' is still accessible!
        private int b2 = ((A this).a;   // OK!
    }
}
```

(Yes ... really!!)

The interesting thing though is that the compilation error you get for the above is:

```
Test.java:7: error: a has private access in Test.A
            private int b = a;
```

The compiler writers have decided to describe this situation as access to a private variable, not as access to a variable that has not been inherited.

---

> My question is if "a" is not inherited when we use "private" modifier but the method is , then there is method print() in class B now

... yes ...

> but "a" is not part of the class since it is private,

No!

That's not what inherit means for a field.  The field `a` is present in every instance of `B`.  It is just that it is not accessible.  You can't name it.

> so how is it that the compiler doesn't throw error when we try to access it by saying scope of "a " is private ?

Because it is there.

---

Opinion: the Java definition of "inherited" with respect to `private` fields and methods is confusing.  Even counter-intuitive.  However, it is what it is.

Answer (score 3):

`print` in `class A` is reachable in `class B` as it's `public` and `class B` is a child of `class A`.

But `print` in `class A` can see all the fields in `class A` since it's a method of that class. So *that* function can see `a`, and hence compilation passes.

Comment: But , that method now belongs to class B does it not ?

Comment: Actually function print doesn't moved to class B, but its being accessible from class B. So function print is being accessible from class B and private property a is accessible from function print.

Answer (score 2):

Field 'a' is inherited. It is not directly accessible from class B.
Only class A can access field a.

Comment: field 'a' is not inherited by B, private modifiers are not inherited, only the method is inherited.

Comment: @StephenC very strange, i've always tought private modifiers are not inherited as the javadoc says:
**A subclass does not inherit the private members of its parent class. However, if the superclass has public or protected methods for accessing its private fields, these can also be used by the subclass.**
But the private modifiers can be accessed via encapsulation.

Comment: Class B has field 'a', but is not accessible - that's a fact.
From implementation point of view: private fields and methods are 'inherited' but they are not visible.
From inheritance concept point of view field 'a' is not inherited.

Comment: @MateuszBalbus So what if i try some other new method like 
public void printB(){ System.out.println(a);}                                                   
Wouldn't compilation fail ?

Comment: It will fail as 'a' is not accessible, but class contains it. You can use Java Reflection API to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing inheritance with visibility/access.

The `a` attribute is not visible/accessible directly from within `B`; but it is definitely inherited, in the sense that it is still there, because an instance of `B` contains an instance of `A` (`class B extends A`), and that instance of `A` (where the `print()` method lives) always contains that `a` attribute.

Comment: Then if i understand correctly , now print( ) is a method in B class , so shouldn't another method also be able to access "a" ?

Comment: other methods of `a`, sure. Other methods of `B` are prevented from doing so because `a` is a private part of class `A`